# Windows Command Prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, java, batch-file

**How to load a prewritten line in command prompt?**

Example:

---

### Take the followings as a line:

```
java -jar System.jar
```

Can this command line be written in a .bat file so that  by clicking on the .bat file it is automatically loaded?

PS: The initial start up of the command prompt has to be

```
C:\Users\[USER]>
```

So the result would therefore be:

Line1:

```
C:\Users\Me> cd
```

Line2:

```
C:\Users\Me> java -jar System.jar
```

**This would prevent one from typing a command over and over again.**

Comment: Yes, batch will do fine, but you maybe should be reading things about batch scripting, not asking questions yet. ;-)

Comment: Batch or Command script file is precisely for that. It started out as a way of not having to retype sequential sets of commands over and over again and has been extended with branch and other logic.

Comment: How is it that it is actually done though because when I use echo off, it clears the 
    C:\Users\[USER]>

Comment: [A Windows Batch File Programming Primer](http://www.vectorsite.net/tsbatch.html)

Comment: A side note: you may want to check out javaw.exe.  It doesn't pop up a console window.

Comment: What is confusing is, how did you know that this question should be tagged `batch-file`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Batch files are really a sequence of commands that when the batch file is double-clicked or run, it runs those commands in order.

In order to create a batch file, use a program like Notepad like so

[image: Batch File in Command Prompt]

The command prompt will execute the cd command first, and then java, and after the java process closes (when your app closes), the command prompt will close automatically. If you want to not wait for the app to finish, you can do `start java -jar System.jar`, and that will tell the command prompt not to wait, and adding a `pause` at the end will tell it to wait.

Now you can save the file, by going in to the File->Save As... dialog, and after you select `All Files (*.*)` in the save as type and name it whatever, remembering to have the .bat extension at the end.

[image: Save Dialog]

Once we open it, we can see that the commands are ran (I added a pause at the end of mine).

[image: Command Prompt when run]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, follow these steps:

1. Open Notepad
2. Enter the following

   > cd %USERPROFILE%
   >    java -jar System.jar
3. Go to **File** » **Save As...**
4. Navigate to where you want to save the batch file.
5. Select "All Files (****.****)" from the **Save as type** drop-down box.
6. Enter `WhateverYouWantToCallIt.bat` in the **File name** text box. The important part of the filename is that it ends with `.bat`.
7. Click on **Save**
8. Run your batch file.

---

Better option: Create a shortcut

1. Right click in the folder you want the shortcut, and click on **New** » **Shortcut**.
2. click on the **Browse** button and navigate to your `Java.exe` path. This should be something like `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe"`.
3. Click **Next**
4. Type in the name of the shortcut, and click on **Finish**.
5. Right click on the newly created shortcut and click on **Properties**.
6. On in the **Target** text box, add the following to the end of the text that is already there (make sure there is space between what is there and the line below).

   > -jar System.jar

   So instead of `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe"` it would say

   > "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe" -jar System.jar
7. Change the text in the **Start in** text-box to `C:\Users\Me`.
8. Optional: Click on **Change Icon** and browse to an .ICO file to use for your shortcut.
9. Click on **OK**